# FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, visual-studio-code

So I'm tring to make an app to show a detail card view page when I click on the gif of the character, so i'm trying to implement the ListView.build() inside an expand that is inside a column. but it gives me this error **FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight.
The offending constraints were:
BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED))**

here it's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_card_pager/vertical_card_pager.dart';
import 'models/hero_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Valorant Agents',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  alert(String msg) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(msg),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: "FECHAR",
        onPressed: () => ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar(),
      ),
    ));
  }

  //ImagesController _imagesController = Get.find();
  //List for agents and respective gif for each one.
  final List<HeroModel> heros = [
    HeroModel("JETT", "images/jett_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("KILLJOY", "images/killjoy_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SAGE", "images/sage_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SOVA", "images/sova_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("VIPER", "images/viper_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("RAZE", "images/raze_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("YORU", "images/yoru_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("BREACH", "images/breach_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("ASTRA", "images/astra_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("CYPHER", "images/cypher_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("OMEN", "images/omen_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("PHOENIX", "images/phoenix_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SKYE", "images/skye_valo.gif"),
  ];

  @override
  //Head Logo
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  ImagesController _imagesController = Get.find();
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 70,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                child: Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "images/logo.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // CardView
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: heros.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return VerticalCardPager(
                      titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
                      images: [
                        for (var hero in heros)
                          Hero(
                            tag: hero.title,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              child: Image.asset(
                                hero.image,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      initialPage: 2,
                      align: ALIGN.CENTER,
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include VerticalCardPager too?

Comment: +from scaffold body, It would be easier if you can provide minimal snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: i just eddited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `Expanded` widget. You are using the `Expanded` widget inside the `Column` whose height is not fixed. You can resolve it by either wrapping column inside `SizedBox` and setting some height or using `shrinkWrap` inside `ListView.builder` and removing the `Expanded` widget.

**Solution 1**

```
       SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 70,
                ...
              ),
              // CardView
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: heros.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      ...
                    }),
              )
            ],
          )
```

**Solution 2:**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 70,
                ...
              ),
              // CardView
              ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: heros.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true, // add this
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    ...
                  })
            ],
          ),
        )
```

**P.S:- If you want to use 2nd solution you need to restrict `ListView` scrolling by setting `physics` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` and wrapping `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView`**

Answer (score 0):

You don't needed to use `VerticalCardPager` inside `listView`, try this:

```
Expanded(
   child: Container(
      child: VerticalCardPager(
        titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
        images: [
             for (var hero in heros)
                Hero(
                  tag: hero.title,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                         hero.image,
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
             color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
             initialPage: 2,
             align: ALIGN.CENTER,
     ),
  ),
)
```